# Is there a mass relation of the core left behind after ejection in a red giant?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, stellar-physics, stellar-evolution

Assuming that you have the mass of the star prior to the ejection of non-core material, is there any relation that can be used to approximate the mass of the resulting left behind core which will later go on to become a white dwarf, neutron star, or other similar core object?

EDIT: I did attempt to find such a relation on my own, but only found unrelated relations or simply that the core exists.  I was unable to locate on my own any relation between mass and core mass.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the supernova type and their mass. Typically, if the original star has about 8 solar masses or less they just become white dwarfs. If greater it's more complex and spends on type/makeup.

The Wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova#Core_collapse
Has a nice treatment and a table of likely remnants for different types and masses.